# How to calculate time difference, and add it up to the starting time?

Tags: r, datetime, plot, linear-regression

I am trying to produce a linear regression model between 2 time points (those displayed as time of the day) - say "dispatched" and "received" - to observe whether there is a specific time of the day (or a timespan) that an item being dispatched that affects its time of arrival.
For example, if an item is dispatched close to lunch time, will it be delivered later than if it were dispatched in the morning?

My dataframe looks something like this:

```
                Dispatched             Received
52756  2018-11-05 11:41:00  2018-11-05 11:49:00
52764  2018-10-05 08:03:00  2018-10-05 08:03:00
52772  2018-08-24 07:36:00  2018-08-24 07:37:00
52780  2018-07-26 07:37:00  2018-07-26 07:40:00
52788  2018-07-12 08:00:00  2018-07-12 08:01:00
52796  2018-05-30 12:54:00  2018-05-31 07:25:00
52805  2018-05-30 12:54:00  2018-05-31 07:25:00
52814  2018-06-14 09:05:00  2018-06-14 09:07:00
52820  2018-06-14 09:05:00  2018-06-14 09:07:00
52826  2018-06-14 09:05:00  2018-06-14 09:07:00
52829  2018-06-14 09:05:00  2018-06-14 09:07:00
52835  2018-06-18 11:00:00  2018-06-19 08:06:00
52843  2018-03-12 11:34:00  2018-03-13 09:53:00
52851  2018-07-03 13:14:00  2018-07-03 13:15:00
52853  2018-07-03 13:14:00  2018-07-03 13:15:00
```

Those dates are already as `POSIXct()` objects.

Next, since I am not interested in the day, I create 2 extra columns with just the time:

```
                Dispatched             Received Disp_time Rcvd_time
52756  2018-11-05 11:41:00  2018-11-05 11:49:00  11:41:00  11:49:00
52764  2018-10-05 08:03:00  2018-10-05 08:03:00  08:03:00  08:03:00
52772  2018-08-24 07:36:00  2018-08-24 07:37:00  07:36:00  07:37:00
52780  2018-07-26 07:37:00  2018-07-26 07:40:00  07:37:00  07:40:00
52788  2018-07-12 08:00:00  2018-07-12 08:01:00  08:00:00  08:01:00
52796  2018-05-30 12:54:00  2018-05-31 07:25:00  12:54:00  07:25:00
52805  2018-05-30 12:54:00  2018-05-31 07:25:00  12:54:00  07:25:00
52814  2018-06-14 09:05:00  2018-06-14 09:07:00  09:05:00  09:07:00
52820  2018-06-14 09:05:00  2018-06-14 09:07:00  09:05:00  09:07:00
52826  2018-06-14 09:05:00  2018-06-14 09:07:00  09:05:00  09:07:00
52829  2018-06-14 09:05:00  2018-06-14 09:07:00  09:05:00  09:07:00
52835  2018-06-18 11:00:00  2018-06-19 08:06:00  11:00:00  08:06:00
52843  2018-03-12 11:34:00  2018-03-13 09:53:00  11:34:00  09:53:00
52851  2018-07-03 13:14:00  2018-07-03 13:15:00  13:14:00  13:15:00
52853  2018-07-03 13:14:00  2018-07-03 13:15:00  13:14:00  13:15:00
```

So, if the time difference is within the same day, I can plot (`ggplot2::ggplot()`) and calculate a regression curve (`ggpubr::stat_cor()`) with no problem.

However if you take a look at, for instance, items "52796", "52805", "52835" and "52843", they are dispatched in one day, but delivered on the next day. And that is the problem when plotting (Disp_time vs Rcvd_time).

So, I was thinking on a way to overcome this by simply adding the time difference to the "Rcvd_time", even if it surpass 24h. For example, these rows:

```
                Dispatched             Received Disp_time Rcvd_time
52796  2018-05-30 12:54:00  2018-05-31 07:25:00  12:54:00  07:25:00
52805  2018-05-30 12:54:00  2018-05-31 07:25:00  12:54:00  07:25:00
52835  2018-06-18 11:00:00  2018-06-19 08:06:00  11:00:00  08:06:00
52843  2018-03-12 11:34:00  2018-03-13 09:53:00  11:34:00  09:53:00
```

Could be represented as:

```
                Dispatched             Received Disp_time Rcvd_time
52796  2018-05-30 12:54:00  2018-05-31 07:25:00  12:54:00  30:29:00
52805  2018-05-30 12:54:00  2018-05-31 07:25:00  12:54:00  30:29:00
52835  2018-06-18 11:00:00  2018-06-19 08:06:00  11:00:00  32:06:00
52843  2018-03-12 11:34:00  2018-03-13 09:53:00  11:34:00  33:19:00
```

Any idea on how to do it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe based on `library(lubridate);x<-"07:25";hm(x)+hours(24)`?

Comment: The time difference of the 6th and 7th rows is just `"19:31:00"`. To add 24 would be wrong.

Comment: Here, stripping the time from the POSIXct entry complicates things. Why not simply subtract Received by Dispatched?

Comment: Thanks, @RuiBarradas 
That approach gets close to what I am looking for. But if I try:
`hm("15:45") + minutes (785)` . I get something weird like this: `"15H 830M 0S"`

Comment: Hi, @spazznolo . I had tried that before. The thing is I don't want simply the difference in minutes (or hours). I want that difference to be added up to "Dispatched" time. For example, if the item was dispatched at **23:25** and arrived at **07:20** the next day, I would like for that to be displayed as **30:45**. The reason why I am looking for this is because then, I could plot a nice correlation curve (Dispatched x Received).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What is the significance of the sum of dispatched and received times?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the `difftime` function.

```
Dispatched <- as.POSIXct('2018-05-30 12:54:00')
Received <- as.POSIXct('2018-05-31 07:25:00')

time_delta <- difftime(Received, Dispatched, units = 'minutes')
time_delta
```

Comment: Thanks @brknparticle. I had performed that before coming here, but only the difference between those 2 time points is not quite what I am looking for. I want the difference to be added up to "Dispatched" time. For example, if the item was dispatched at **23:25** and arrived at **07:20** the next day, I would like for that to be displayed as **30:45**. The reason why I am looking for this is because then, I could plot a nice correlation curve (Dispatched x Received).